# Build table from property array using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I have a SimpleTable class and VersionList class. The VersionList render method calls the SimpleTable component like so:

```
render() {
    return(
        <SimpleTable ariaLabel="Version Table" columns={this.columns} data={this.state.versionList} />
    );
}
```

The two arrays would eventually look like this:

```
columns = [
    {
        Header: "Developer",
        accessor: "developerName"
    },
    {
        Header: "Software",
        accessor: "softwareName"
    },
        Header: "Version",
        accessor: "softwareVersion"
    },
    {
        id: "editButton",
        sortable: false,
        filterable: false,
        width: 100,
        accessor: "self",
        Cell: ({value}) => ( <Button onClick{() => this.onEditButton(value)}>Edit</Button>
    }
]

/* After going through componentDidMount: */

this.state.data = [
    0: {
        developerName: "JSoft",
        softwareName: "PickleSort",
        softwareVersion: "5.25.4",
        self: "rest_url_to_self_id"
    },
    1: {
        developerName: "JSoft",
        softwareName: "PickleSort2",
        softwareVersion: "5.25.4",
        self: "rest_url_to_self_id"
    },
    0: {
        developerName: "Jackeye",
        softwareName: "Nibble",
        softwareVersion: "1.2.1",
        self: "rest_url_to_self_id"
    }
]
```

Now, SimpleTable will not know what the data array will look like. Which is why the column array is supplied. This way I can display a table which uses the Header entry. Then, subsequent rows under the header will display the relevant information. In the end the table should look like the following (from the above example):

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| Developer       | Software       | Version                     |
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| JSoft           | PickleSort     | 5.25.4            | Edit    | /* index: 0 */
| JSoft           | PickleSort2    | 5.25.4            | Edit    | /* index: 1 */
| Jackeye         | Nibble         | 1.2.1             | Edit    | /* index: 2 */
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The code behind the table header is as follows:

```
<Table>
    <TableHead>
        <TableRow>
            {this.props.columns.map((item, index) => (
                <TableCell key={index}>{item.Header}</TableCell>
            ))}
        <TableRow>
    </TableHead>
</Table>
```

I then need to create something which the table can work with to be able to display the relevant information under each header, but keep the index (see table above).

Comment: this.state.data is invalid data in javascript, please check that

Comment: How is it invalid? It would be built within ```componentDidMount``` and it is built properly within my app?

Comment: He means you can't have an array with numbers as keys and objects as values but rather you should have an array of objects or a dictionary (associative array in js).

Comment: Oh, sorry, no the actual array does not have the 0, 1, 2, I'm just showing each group which will have the key, value pairs in it

Comment: Do you use material ui?

Comment: I am using material ui